# Kafka Connect failing to flush records to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm running a simple Kafka docker instance and trying to insert data into Elasticsearch instance, however I'm seeing this kind of exception:

```
[2018-01-08 16:17:20,839] ERROR Failed to execute batch 36528 of 1 records after total of 6 attempt(s) (io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.bulk.BulkProcessor)
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:139)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:155)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:284)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
        at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
        at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:48)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.BulkIndexingClient.execute(BulkIndexingClient.java:57)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.BulkIndexingClient.execute(BulkIndexingClient.java:34)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.bulk.BulkProcessor$BulkTask.execute(BulkProcessor.java:350)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.bulk.BulkProcessor$BulkTask.call(BulkProcessor.java:327)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.bulk.BulkProcessor$BulkTask.call(BulkProcessor.java:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My Connect config is as follows:

```json
{
  "name": "elasticsearch-analysis",
  "config": {
    "tasks.max": 1,
    "topics": "analysis",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "connection.url": "http://elasticsearch:9200",
    "topic.index.map": "analysis:analysis",
    "schema.ignore": true,
    "key.ignore": false,
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema_registry:8081",
    "type.name": "analysis",
    "batch.size": 200,
    "flush.timeout.ms": 600000,
    "transforms":"insertKey,extractId",
    "transforms.insertKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
    "transforms.insertKey.fields": "Id",
    "transforms.extractId.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "transforms.extractId.field":"Id"
  }
}
```

There's not much data int the topic, just about 70000 unique messages.

As you can see, I've increased flush time and reduced batch sizes, but I still experience these timeouts.

I was unable to find what could've been the fix for it.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue ? I am also facing a similar error.

Comment: @krajwade No, unfortunately...

Comment: Ok. I have raised this issue [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/issues/189)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible your index is refreshing too quickly (the default is 1 second). Try and updating it to something less frequent or even turning it off initially.

```
curl -X PUT http://$ES_HOST/$ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX_NEW/_settings \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
{
    "index" : {
        "refresh_interval" : "15s"
    }
}'
```